# Merging pages in a pdf

Tags: pdf, merge, page

Is there a free program that allows you to merge several pdf pages into one page? For example, suppose I had an eight-page document. Is there a program that would allow me to produce therefrom a "two-page" document with pages 1-4 on the front side and pages 5-8 on the back?

(Note: I am **not** asking how to merge several pdf files into a single file.)

Comment: This is a question for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @YisroelTech, this can be done with current software, without needing a recommendation for new.

Comment: Maybe, but his question was "Is there a free program that allows..." which is looking for a software recommendation.

Comment: ask at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Using adobe acrobat, you can select layout options and change the "pages per sheet." To shrink four pages of the original document, you would select 4.  You can also turn on 2-sided printing. Then save as PDF instead of actually printing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of applications that can print more than one page to a single sheet, such as free [LibreOffice Writer](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.1/en-US/text/swriter/guide/print_small.html) (available for Windows, Mac, Linux and other OS) and [PDF_XChange Editor](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-editor) (a Windows app, but it runs well under wine in Linux). If you prefer to *save* the output as PDF, rather than printing directly, just use the built-in "Print to PDF" capability in your OS.

[image: Multi-page printing]

This shows the print dialog of *PDF_XChange Editor* on Windows OS. Note the preview pane, and ability to have pages arranged horizontally or vertically, making it easier to format the output.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your definition of free, you can use cpdf from https://community.coherentpdf.com/ and do:

`cpdf -impose-xy "2 2" in.pdf -o out.pdf`

You could then follow up with a `-scale-to-fit` command to get your desired page size:

`cpdf -scale-to-fit a4portrait out.pdf -o out2.pdf`